# Execute jmap inside java program to generate dumps for the same process

Tags: java, heap-memory, jmap

Is it possible to execute 'jmap' at different spots inside my java-programm to generate dump files. I guess one must get the own process ID and than execute the command via `Runtime().exec()` or similar. Didn't succeed though.

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
String[] str = name.split("@");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jmap -dump:file=YOURFILENAME " + str[0]);
```